# what‘s the wrong width my Elasticsearch script？

Tags: elasticsearch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDGTC.jpg)

what‘s the wrong width my Elasticsearch script？

elasticsearch version：7.2.0

```
POST /voc_business_publicopinion/_update_by_query
{
  "script": { 
    "source" : """
      for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'].length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < params.leafList.length; ++j) {
          if (ctx._source.extract_opinion.question[i][params.leafList[j].levelKey] && ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'][i][params.leafList[j].levelKey + '_id'] == params.leafList[j]['value']) {
            ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'][i]['priority'] = params.leafList[j]['priority'];
          }
        }
      }
      ctx._source.extract_opinion.should_mark_duplicate=true;
      """,
    "params": {
      "leafList": [{
        "levelKey": "cls_5",
        "value": "CL0062A020",
        "priority": 10000
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand wath's the wrong with my script

[ctx._source.extract_opinion.question] is array list

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "if (ctx._source.extract_opinion.question[i][params.leafList[j].levelKey] && ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'][i][params.leafList[j].levelKey + '_id'] == params.leafList[j]['value']) {\n            ",
          "                                           ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "      for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'].length; ++i) {\n        for (int j = 0; j < params.leafList.length; ++j) {\n          if (ctx._source.extract_opinion.question[i][params.leafList[j].levelKey] && ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'][i][params.leafList[j].levelKey + '_id'] == params.leafList[j]['value']) {\n            ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'][i]['priority'] = params.leafList[j]['priority'];\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      ctx._source.extract_opinion.should_mark_duplicate=true;",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "if (ctx._source.extract_opinion.question[i][params.leafList[j].levelKey] && ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'][i][params.leafList[j].levelKey + '_id'] == params.leafList[j]['value']) {\n            ",
      "                                           ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "      for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'].length; ++i) {\n        for (int j = 0; j < params.leafList.length; ++j) {\n          if (ctx._source.extract_opinion.question[i][params.leafList[j].levelKey] && ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'][i][params.leafList[j].levelKey + '_id'] == params.leafList[j]['value']) {\n            ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'][i]['priority'] = params.leafList[j]['priority'];\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      ctx._source.extract_opinion.should_mark_duplicate=true;",
    "lang": "painless",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "class_cast_exception",
      "reason": "class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

one of my doc :

```
{
  "_index" : "voc_business_publicopinion",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "643d7f10fc236cf0eb35d90ea13a264c",
  "_score" : 0.0,
  "_source" : {
    "extract_opinion" : {
      "from_item" : "sougou",
      "update_time" : "2020-11-26 18:12:37",
      "cost" : 2253,
      "question" : [
        {
          "cls_5" : "外观好看",
          "priority" : "1467",
          "cls_2" : "硬件",
          "cls_2_id" : "CL2",
          "cls_1" : "产品",
          "cls_3_id" : "CL062",
          "cls_4" : "外观结构",
          "cls_1_id" : "PD",
          "cls_3" : "外观结构",
          "cls_5_id" : "CL0062A020",
          "cls_4_id" : "CL0062"
        }
      ],
      "should_mark_duplicate" : false
    }
  }
}
```

part of my doc mapping:

```
"extract_opinion" : {
  "properties" : {
    "question" : {
      "type" : "nested",
      "properties" : {
        "cls_1" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cls_1_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cls_2" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cls_2_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cls_3" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cls_3_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cls_4" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cls_4_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cls_5" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cls_5_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "priority" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "should_mark_duplicate" : {
      "type" : "boolean"
    }
  }
}
```

by the way, is there another way to update docs by query without script?

Comment: I think that `params.leafList[j].levelKey` is a string and not a number. As you're using that as an array index, it has to be an integer or transformed to an integer. Can you share a sample document and your mapping?

Comment: Ok, I have add the doc sample and mapping to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice job! Your script is almost correct. You just need to add an explicit null check in your first if condition:

```
      if (ctx._source.extract_opinion.question[i][params.leafList[j].levelKey] != null && ctx._source['extract_opinion']['question'][i][params.leafList[j].levelKey + '_id'] == params.leafList[j]['value']) {
                                                                               ^^^^^^^
                                                                               |||||||
```

Adding that will make your update by query call work as you expect.